# Order of multiple Channel#write

Tags: netty

I'm reading the Javadoc of Channel of Netty: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html

In my single thread (**outside Netty's IO thread**), if I call `Channel#write` many times:

```
channel.write(msg1);
channel.write(msg2);
channel.write(msg3);
```

Will Netty ensure that the messages be output in order: msg1, msg2, msg3?
Or must I manually ensure the order myself (very tedious, very ugly)?

```
ChannelFuture f1 = channel.write(msg1);
f1.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
  public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
    ChannelFuture f2 = channel.write(msg2);
    f2.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
      public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        channel.write(msg3);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is yes

Channel is thread-safe, which means it is safe to operate on it from different
Threads. Also, this method guarantees that the messages are written in the same order as you passed
them to the write method